# Javascript for loop, counter inside?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm a beginner learning loops.

I made a for loop like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log("Counting...");
}
```

As expected I get the output "Counting..." five times.

I modified the loop and put the counter inside it instead (maybe you shouldn't do this, I'm just trying things out).

```
for (i = 0; i < 5;) {
    console.log("Counting...");
    i++
}
```

Now i get:

```
Counting...
Counting...
Counting...
Counting...
Counting...
4
```

Where is this 4 coming from? What does it mean?

Comment: There is no `4` that gets printed: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vFANg/). You must have another `console.log` somewhere after.

Comment: You should have got `"Counting..."` five times followed by an `undefined` in the first case?

Comment: work fine in chrome, I do not see `4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are runnig this in Developer Tools or similar. "4" isn't actually printed, it's the return value of the last statement from the for loop.

When you ran your first loop, you probably saw this:

```
Counting...
Counting...
Counting...
Counting...
Counting...
undefined
```

(undefined is a return value in first case, because `console.log()` does not return anything). In second case, `undefined` is being replaced by `4`.

Comment: Thank's, this clears it up. I didn't see any 'undefined' being printed out on Codeacademy where I'm doing this, maybe they strip it out. When I put my first loop in my own console, I did get undefined.

Comment: This is added as a convienience in development. To quickly evaluate some expression, you only have to type "2 + 5" and not "console.log(2 + 5);"